# Maven : Package not found when clean install

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-2, executable-jar

My project in Spring boot. I have one external jar file in my project and I added only through Build path. When I ran my project using maven clean install command. I got following error message :

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/Code/workspace/NestOrion/src/main/java/orion/trader/individual/IndividualOrderTrader.java:[16,33] package com.omnesys.nestq.classes does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Code/workspace/NestOrion/src/main/java/orion/trader/individual/IndividualOrderTrader.java:[17,33] package com.omnesys.nestq.classes does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Code/workspace/NestOrion/src/main/java/orion/trader/individual/IndividualOrderTrader.java:[36,28] cannot find symbol
```

Pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.orion.main.NestOrionApplication
                        </mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I read other article also as per them some time external jar file path not found at run time so we need to java classpath (Source attachment). So I added through Build path > jar > added source attachment. But Still I am getting the same compile error .

Comment: you need to add your external jar as compile time `<dependency>`

Comment: How ? could you please tell me?

Comment: you can google 'add maven dependency ' there are multiple resources

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Comment: What do you mean by `and I added only through Build path..`? Please show the full pom file

Answer (score 1):

It solved my issue after added my external jar in maven dependency.

Steps :

1. create libs folder in your project. Right click on project > New > Folder > libs
2. Put your external jar file in that folder.
3. Open pom.xml file and add that dependency into your code.

Name of jar : ReleaseVersion.jar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>DealerNestQApiReleaseVersion</groupId>
        <artifactId>DealerNestQApiReleaseVersion</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/DealerNestQApiReleaseVersion.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

4. Add following code in maven.

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

By using this steps I solved my issue.